# C# Client for JSON-RPC API

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, websocket, rpc

I'm trying to send requests to an API that talks JSON-RPC. I've tested the server with Curl as such:

```
> curl -v -d 'SOME_INVALID_REQUEST' http://erbium1.sytes.net:50001
 {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "error": {"code": -32700, "message": "invalid JSON"}, "id": null}
```

Some of the requests that interest me are subscriptions, thus sending POST requests seem unfit for this because I don't expect the server to reply instantly, rather receive one or more notifications.

I'm trying to talk to this server using C#, but the server never replies. To send the messages I've done the following :

1. Created a [TcpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)
2. Connected the client to the server (erbium1.sytes.net,50001)
3. Go a [NetworkStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Sockets_TcpClient_GetStream) from the connected client
4. Wrote to the NetworkStream
   When I send these messages to the server, the read callback function is never invoked thus I am never receiving replies from the server. If I were to send the messages to port 50002 (TLS) instead of 50001, the server replies with an empty string.

My guess is, doing a raw TcpClient connection does not send the messages with the HTTP headers thus the server is just dropping them? If so, what would be a suitable way of requesting subscriptions to the server and be able to receive notifications?

What would be the difference between a TcpClient connection and a WebSocket? Would WebSocket be the suitable thing to use here?

Below a sample of my code :

```
// State object for receiving data from remote device.
public class ReceiverState {
    public ReceiverState(NetworkStream s) {
        this.stream = s;
    }
    public NetworkStream stream;
    public const int bufferSize = 1024;
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    public AutoResetEvent receivedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
}



  static AutoResetEvent received = new AutoResetEvent(false);

  public static void PingServer(NetworkStream stream) {
      if (stream.CanWrite) {
          try {
              String rpc = "INVALID_REQUEST";
              Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rpc);
              stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
              stream.Flush();
              Console.WriteLine("Pinging...");
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
          }
      } else {
          // TODO Throw an exception
          Console.WriteLine("Unable to write to stream");
      }
  }

  public static void BeginAsyncRead(NetworkStream stream, ReceiverState readState) {
      if (stream.CanRead) {
          try {
              stream.BeginRead(readState.buffer, 0, 1024,
                               new AsyncCallback(readCallBack),
                               readState);
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
              Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
          }
      } else {
          // TODO Throw an exception
          Console.WriteLine("Unable to read from stream");
      }
  }

  private static void readCallBack(System.IAsyncResult ar) {
      // Get the state from AsyncResult
      ReceiverState state = (ReceiverState) ar.AsyncState;

      if(ar.IsCompleted){
          Int32 numBytes = state.stream.EndRead(ar);
          Console.WriteLine("Received : ");
          Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer,0,numBytes+10));
          state.receivedEvent.Set();
      }
  }

  private static void synchronousRead(NetworkStream myNetworkStream) {
      if(myNetworkStream.CanRead){
          byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
          StringBuilder myCompleteMessage = new StringBuilder();
          int numberOfBytesRead = 0;

          // Incoming message may be larger than the buffer size.
          do{
              numberOfBytesRead = myNetworkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
              myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
          }
          while(myNetworkStream.DataAvailable);
          // Print out the received message to the console.
          Console.WriteLine("You received the following message : " +
                            myCompleteMessage);
      }
      else{
          Console.WriteLine("Sorry.  You cannot read from this NetworkStream.");
      }
  }

  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    // Create a new TcpClient
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    Console.WriteLine("Connecting...");
    client.Connect("electrum3.hachre.de", 50001);
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    Stream inStream = new MemoryStream();
    ReceiverState readState = new ReceiverState(stream);
    readState.receivedEvent = received;
    BeginAsyncRead(stream, readState);
    PingServer(stream);
    received.WaitOne();
  }
```

Comment: TCP is the transport layer for HTTP.  TCP only sends raw data and you must add any http headers.  A net websocket would add default headers.  You can learn a lot by using a sniffer like wireshark that will give you all the IP messages being sent.

Comment: @jdweng to my understanding it is possible to establish a persistent connection via websocket, if so, would every request sent have the appropriate headers? Or only an initial handshake to establish the websocket? Do web APIs by default expect messages to be received with the default HTTP headers?

Comment: The TCP connection stays open between requests.  Each HTTP message has a header but initial header can have more options than subsequent messages.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol Web APIs can use any IP Protocol.  I think in this case Web refers to any IP Protocol, not just HTTP.  Most web api do use http.  But some are SMTP (email) and FTP (File Transfer) which are enhanced forms of http.  You can have TELNET API which are simple TCP chat applications.